# xslt how to get the parent node position for the case same node name is also child node

Tags: xslt

I would like to add color for the alternative table row. I would like to use the following method:

```
<xsl:template match="tr">
<xsl:attribute name="bg-color">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test= position() mod 2 = 0><xsl:text>#CCCCCC</xsl:text></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>#DDDDDD</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

But things is the node `<tr>`is also the child of tag `<tr>`. how do i get the parent `<tr>` position?

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

how do i filter out the `<tr>` inside of the `<tr>`?

Comment: edited my post as you found out that it was table/tr/td/table/tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a more discriminant match like if you can't have more than 1 level :

```
<xsl:template match="table/tr/td/table/tr">
```

The template that would be applied to your tr contained in a level 2 table could then be different from the other one.

Or you could use a call template (to a named tempate) in your match="tr" for each table/tr/td found.

Or you could check if ancestor is tr with xsl:if:

```
<xsl:if test="ancestor::tr">
```

You already check the modularity, then just add a condition if you do not want to add a template, something like:

```
test="position() mod 2 = 0 and not ancestor::tr"
```

Comment: well I'm working on a very big xsl stylesheet which applies to all the production environment. add another template will probably impact to lots of place which i cannot take risk. I would like to only filter out the child tr using the xPath instead of another template.

Comment: @xslnewMember: actually, typically if you update stylesheets, you do that by adding new matching templates to deal with certain new, exceptional cases. It is much harder to retain the structure and remain expandable with pull-style xpaths. If you don't want to disrupt, write extra matching templates, and/or add certain priorities.

Comment: I would like to try <xsl:if test="../name()=tr"> :)

Comment: you can try with count(preceding-sibling::tr) mod 2 = 0 or something like that may work, but i still don't understand why you don't just add a match or a condition on the parent.

Comment: yes I did but my situation is that A real newbie has to work on very complicated stylesheet AND HAS TO FINISH WITHIN TIME LIMITATION

Comment: it's always like that when you start xslt... just try and try until you get what you want, then check you didnt introduced any regression in the code. There are always many ways to do a single thing so try all by yourself until you are satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `match="table/tr"` then the template matches only `tr` elements that are children of a `table` parent element. But a tr as a child of a tr is not possible in the HTML table model.

Comment: same idea with add a new template. I would like to try it out later but will try the <xsl:if test="../name()=tr"> first.

Comment: just found out that the data is like table/tr/td/table/tr/td; so match="table/tr" cannot filter out the child table/tr

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:if test="ancestor::tr">` and `test="position() mod 2 = 0 and not ancestor::tr"` are the best choice for my case.